# Problem with dual boot with Dell Latitude 5400

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, dell

I have dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and until recently it was working perfectly! However around two weeks ago there was BIOS update (to version 1.6.5) and since then I am not able to boot to Ubuntu if the laptop is running on battery only, when running with AC adapter the booting process is successful. The boot to W10 is working without any issue.
Are there any suggestions how to solve this problem??

Thank you!

Comment: This seems very oddly specific, I would rummage through the BIOS - **do not change any settings before researching them** - as BIOS updates may revert some settings back to factory default. The main settings you would be looking for would be close to the bottom of the bios under Power Management, and see if anything looks like it would feasibly disable your ability to boot.

Comment: I tried to look for something but the  Powersupply manager looks unchanged :( others I dare to touch..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Reinstall bios version 1.5.1
- Disable automatic update
- Wait for a dell fix version to 1.6.5 of the unexplained error.

Dell does not assume the error.

Comment: I tried to contact Dell first but their answer was that this particular laptop was shipped with preinstalled W10 which is working and therefore it is not their problem :-/

Comment: 2 option:
disable TuboBoost
will work with the standard, being able to use bios 1.6.5, will have loss but can use.

Comment: Disabling the TurboBoost really helped!! thanks a lot Luciano Ferreira!!